# How to Speed up Java Program to update excel cell values (Excel has 30000 records)?

Tags: java, string, apache-poi

I have an EXCEL file which has more than 30K records. I wanted to update some of the cell values like if the cell values has '#' it will replace with "-". So, developed a Java program which can do the task.

But the program is very slow when it is running on the entire excel records. The excel size is less than 5MB but it takes like 1 seconds for each record. So, it is taking more than one hour to process the excel file.

**Any suggestion to improve the performance of this Java program.**

My Java code looks like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "formatted.xlsx";

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

        Cell description = row.getCell(3); // category
        String descriptionText = description.getStringCellValue();
        String modifiedDescription = descriptionText.replace("#", "-");
        description.setCellValue(modifiedDescription);
        
        System.out.println(i + modifiedDescription);

        file.close();

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: open and close the file only 1 time; remove system.out

Answer (score 2):

You open and close `outFile` on every single row.  I can pretty much guarantee that this is the source of your performance problems, because filesystem operations are relatively slow.

Pull the file opening out of the loop like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "formatted.xlsx";

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

        Cell description = row.getCell(3); // category
        String descriptionText = description.getStringCellValue();
        String modifiedDescription = descriptionText.replace("#", "-");
        description.setCellValue(modifiedDescription);
        
        System.out.println(i + modifiedDescription);
        workbook.write(outFile);
    }
    file.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```